# SWIFT Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift

Good day everyone,
I need your help on the following :
I have a swift file where I store different functions used by different Class swift files.

Here is a part of one of these functions:

```
            strStatus = "STEP 1/8 : Downloading data..."

            if myView == "C" {
                CDetails().lblStatus1.text = strStatus // Here is the error
            }
            else if myView == "A" {
                Alerts().lblStatus4.text = strStatus
            }
```

Then I have 2 Class, CDetails and Alerts, which can call this function.
Depending on the Class, a message is to be displayed in a label.
However, when I execute the code I get the following error:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

I read different topics related to this problem but was not able to sort it out. So I would be grateful if you could be of any help!
I thank you in advance for your assistance on this!

Comment: There's a question with a near duplicate title. Are you sure that's not the solution? Sounds like your property can't be `nil` but it is.

Comment: what is your CDetails() inside?

Comment: `CDetails()`, that's a UIView or a UIViewController? You know that's creating a new one, and not the one that you might see on screen? Also, `lblStatus1` or `lblStatus4` wasn't load yet (I guess it's an IBOutlet). So could you clarify a little the screens logic here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: CDetails is a UIViewController. Now I realize that with () I was creating a new one. However I cannot figure out the way to point to lblStatus1 on CDetails. Indeed when I write CDetails followed by a point, I do not have any lblStatus member choice after the point. How can I designate lblStatus (which is a UILabel) located on CDetails (which is a UIViewController) when I call it from out of CDetails class?

Comment: Where is `CDetails`, where is `Alerts`? What's the logic between them and the current code? Where is your current code? In the "previous view controller"? A later one? A non-viewcontroller? Etc.

Comment: Thank you Larme for your follow up, much appreciated!
From CDetails viewController when I click on a cmd button it calls a function located on a non-viewController in another swift file. I do that because the called function is used by different viewControllers and I do not want to copy paste this function to all of them.
Then, depending on the viewController who called this function (e.g CDetails, Alerts or others), I need to access to their own UITextFields, UILabels).
Problem is : From a non-viewController, when I write CDetails I have no TextField nor Labels members after the point.